# Assign multiple variables using sql for loop

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I need to assign many date value based on one date value by incrementing the date.

Following code is a sample. but it throws error. where i am wrong kindly advice.

```
   DECLARE
     issuedate date:='27-JAN-12';
     issuedate_1 date;
     issuedate_2 date;
     issuedate_3 date;
   BEGIN
     for cnt in 1..5
     loop
       issuedate_||cnt := issuedate+cnt;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cnt);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( issuedate_1);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( issuedate_2);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( issuedate_3);
     end loop;
   END;
```

Comment: Since you can get the value to be stored in "issuedate_n" by just using "issue_date + n", you do not need these variables.

Comment: Hi David ,is that possible to do in my way ha...

Comment: I'm saying that you do not need those variables, as their values can be determined from the value of issuedate

Comment: i got your point but i need to insert the output into a table as a one row data. it means i am going to get five values means i need to insert the as coloumn data based on the issue date.

Comment: well that's no better, as you're breaking normalisation practice by inserting values which are derivable from each other. If you really want to do that then insert issue_date+1, not issuedate_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't form the variable name dynamically, create array of dates and increment and assign values.
[TRY THIS LINK](http://psoug.org/reference/arrays.html)

**issuedate_||cnt** := issuedate+cnt;--problem is in **BOLD** part

Sample :

```
SQL>   declare
  2  
  3        type date_aa is table of date index by pls_integer;
  4        l_date_aa date_aa;
  5        temp date:= to_date('27-mar-2012');
  6        buckets number:=5;
  7     begin
  8      for elem in 1 .. buckets loop
  9    select temp+1 into temp from dual;
 10    l_date_aa(elem) := temp;
 11    dbms_output.put_line(l_date_aa(elem));
 12    end loop;
 13    end;
 14  /
```

output:

```
28-MAR-12
29-MAR-12
30-MAR-12
31-MAR-12
01-APR-12

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: this is very exactly what you want. check this.I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use plsql collections to assign the date values instead of 100 variables

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE
 issuedate date  ; 
 l_issuedate date;
 BEGIN
 issuedate := TO_DATE('27-JAN-12') ;
 for cnt in 0..5
 loop
   SELECT issuedate+cnt
     INTO l_issuedate
     FROM DUAL ;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_issuedate);

 end loop;
END;
```

Out put :

```
27-JAN-12
28-JAN-12
29-JAN-12
30-JAN-12
31-JAN-12
01-FEB-12
```

Comment: I want to assign the date to multiple variables based on the looping incrementation.

Comment: Then better to use plsql table type